# Does Nexus 2.x OSS support multiple versions/automatic age off?

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I'm looking to use the OSS version of Nexus 2 for artefact management? Does it support automatic retention and removal of multiple versions of an artefact so that only so many versions are retained?

Example:

I'd like Nexus to automatically (via some config settings) to just keep the last 3 versions of an artefact in a repo:

```
myrpm_v5.rpm <-- latest (keep)
myrpm_v4.rpm <-- latest -1 (keep)
myrpm_v3.rpm <-- latest -2 (keep)
myrpm_v2.rpm <-- automatically remove when v5 is added 
myrpm_v1.rpm <-- removed
```

Is this supported (couldn't see anything in the product matrix)? I'm using Nexus 2 (but could consider 3)

Comment: If this is a maven repo, you can use the 'remove releases from repository' task to do that:  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM2/Managing+Scheduled+Tasks

Comment: In addition to what @rseddon wrote Nexus Repository Manager 3 doesn't have this functionality yet but when implemented should be for all formats if that can be managed: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10821.  These two facts could be combined into an answer if you relay what format you are seeking (or your question was general).